# How to keep Letter Case in JSON Converter method in Groovy?

Tags: java, json, grails, groovy

I'm trying to parse a groovy object to JSON. The properties names don't follow the correct camel case form.

```
class Client {
    String Name
    Date Birthdate
}
```

When I use this

```
Client client = new Client(Name: 'Richard Waters', Birthdate: new Date())
println (client as JSON).toString(true)
```

I got this

```
"client": {
      "name": 'Richard Waters',
      "birthdate": "2016-07-22T03:00:00Z",
}
```

How can I keep de Upper Case in start of my properties keys?

Comment: You're using a weird format... Probably best use something like Jackson if you want to go off piste... Camel case is the norm, with lower case starting letters. Especially for variable names in groovy

Comment: I understand that camel case is the norm. But the API that I'm working on defines these weird format! =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use a `gson serializer` with annotations: https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html

```
@Grab('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7+')
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

class Client {
    @SerializedName("Name")
    String name

    @SerializedName("Birthdate")
    Date birthdate
}

def client = new Client(name: 'John', birthdate: new Date())

def strJson = new Gson().toJson(client)
println strJson
```

Answer (score -1):

Well you are breaking standard naming convention and hence it automatically converts it to camel case.

Hence, if you want to override the camel case, one option is write your custom method that overrides `object.getProperties()` aka `object.properties` to return a custom map as internally the map created uses `getName()` method of `MetaProperty.java` class rather than getting the real property name.

Hence, the only job you have to perform is to write a custom generic method that converts your object to map.

And then if you use object as JSON it will return expected json.

For example

```
class Client {
    String name
}

Client client = new Client(name: 'Richard Waters')
println (["Name":"test"] as grails.converters.JSON)
```

Here in map Name's N is capital and is returned capital in json too. 
Hope it helps!!

Comment: There's no "standard naming convention" in JSON. If Groovy's JSON implementation doesn't interoperate with existing JSON formats, then the implementation is incomplete.