# groovy JSON builder need to remove white spaces

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I am trying to build a JSON Using Groovy JSON builder.
The code used is as script in JSR223 is as below:
Code used :

```
**def previousResponse = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseData())
@groovy.transform.Immutable
class Package {
    String ReferenceId
    String Name
    String Version
    Integer Size
}
def packages = previousResponse.Packages.collect { Package -> new Package(Package.ReferenceId, Package.Name, Package.LastVersion.Version, Package.LastVersion.Size) }
def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
builder(HasDraftVersion: false,
        IsApprovalPending: null,
        IsInstalledSilently: true,
        LastModified: "/Date(1535570626907)/",
        LastModifiedBy: "Administrator",
        DeviceConfigurations: [],
        Packages: packages.collect(),
        LdapTargets: null,
        ReferenceId: null,
        DeviceFamily: 6,
        DeviceFamilyQualification: 0,
        Name: "test",
        Description: "",
        Random: "2018-08-29T15:16:47",
        IsPublicAPI: true)
sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('',builder.toString(),'')
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true);        

The result I am getting from the above code is correct and is in the format:
```

**{"HasDraftVersion":false,"IsApprovalPending":null,"IsInstalledSilently":true,"LastModified":"/Date(1535661532840)/","LastModifiedBy":"Administrator","DeviceConfigurations":[],"Packages":[{"referenceId":"282812e7-c3e6-4ecb-8267-bbe2c250ad59","version":"1.0","size":10465294,"name":"10MB","packageDependencies":""},{"referenceId":"02f5b531-8e37-42c1-bfcb-ec8db0920bed","version":"1.0","size":104884390,"name":"100MB","packageDependencies":""}],"LdapTargets":null,"ReferenceId":null,"DeviceFamily":6,"DeviceFamilyQualification":0,"Name":"work","Description":"","Random":"2018-08-30T04:38:52","IsPublicAPI":true}**

The issue I am facing is with the sequence of label and values like the sequence for Packages tag should have been :

ReferenceID , Name , Version PackageDependencies

The error I am getting when I pass the same to the next HTTP Request is

**{"Data":null,"ErrorCode":0,"ErrorMessage":"Parameter 'ReferenceId' has invalid value ''.","HelpLink":null,"InnerErrors":[{"Data":["ReferenceId",""],"ErrorCode":2,"ErrorMessage":"Parameter 'ReferenceId' has invalid value ''.","HelpLink":null,"InnerErrors":null,"Ref":"2018-08-30 16:38:52.9245-04:00"}],"Ref":"2018-08-30 16:38:52.9245-04:00"}**

The ReferenceId is being passed and result is there for the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Groovy is converting maps names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545194/how-to-keep-letter-case-in-json-converter-method-in-groovy) to match [naming convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html)

So in order to keep these `ReferenceID` parameter and friends as they are and not in the camel case you need to amend this line:

```
Packages: packages.collect()
```

with this ones:

```
Packages: packages.collect() {
     [
             ReferenceId        : it.ReferenceId,
             Name               : it.Name,
             Version            : it.Version,
             PackageDependencies: "",
             Size               : it.Size
     ]
 },
```

Full code just in case:

```
def previousResponse = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseData())

@groovy.transform.Immutable
class Package {
    String ReferenceId
    String Name
    String Version
    Integer Size
}

def packages = previousResponse.Packages.collect { Package -> new Package(Package.ReferenceId, Package.Name, Package.LastVersion.Version, Package.LastVersion.Size) }

def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()

builder(HasDraftVersion: false,
        IsApprovalPending: null,
        IsInstalledSilently: true,
        LastModified: "/Date(1535570626907)/",
        LastModifiedBy: "Administrator",
        DeviceConfigurations: [],
        Packages: packages.collect() {
            [
                    ReferenceId        : it.ReferenceId,
                    Name               : it.Name,
                    Version            : it.Version,
                    PackageDependencies: "",
                    Size               : it.Size
            ]
        },
        LdapTargets: null,
        ReferenceId: null,
        DeviceFamily: 6,
        DeviceFamilyQualification: 0,
        Name: "test",
        Description: "",
        Random: "2018-08-29T15:16:47",
        IsPublicAPI: true)

sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('',builder.toPrettyString(),'')
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true);
```

More information:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Writing JMeter Functions in Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/writing-jmeter-functions-in-groovy)